# How to change the marker size in a swarmplot

Tags: python, seaborn, swarmplot

I would like to make the data points on my swarmplot larger. The code I have is:

```
sns.swarmplot(x="Heart", y="FirstPersonPronouns", hue="Speech", data=df)
sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.8)
```

I have tried `scatter_kws` but get:

```
Attribute error: unknown property scatter_kws.
```

Answer (score 8):

From the swarmplot docstring:

```
Signature: seaborn.swarmplot(x=None, y=None, hue=None, data=None,
order=None, hue_order=None, split=False, orient=None, color=None, 
palette=None, size=5, edgecolor='gray', linewidth=0, ax=None,
**kwargs)
Docstring: Draw a categorical scatterplot with non-overlapping points.     
[snip]


Parameters
---------- 
x, y, hue : names of variables in ``data`` or vector data, optional
    Inputs for plotting long-form data. See examples for interpretation. 
data : DataFrame, array, or list of arrays, optional
    Dataset for plotting. If ``x`` and ``y`` are absent, this is
    interpreted as wide-form. Otherwise it is expected to be long-form. [snip]
```

And then:

```
size : float, optional
    Diameter of the markers, in points. (Although ``plt.scatter`` is used
    to draw the points, the ``size`` argument here takes a "normal"
    markersize and not size^2 like ``plt.scatter``.
```